# Getting the DB name of the spatialite table loaded inside QGIS using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2

I have a table loaded in QGIS from spatialite DB. When i see the layer properties it is **dbname='/home/farook/Spatialite/Cities.sqlite' table="cities" sql=**. Now i want the dbname alone (i.e) the entire path **'/home/farook/Spatialite/Cities.sqlite'** for whatever layer loaded inside QGIS dynamically using PyQGIS. Is there any options for the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two code statements will provide the table path to the db name:

```
print iface.activeLayer().dataProvider().dataSourceUri().split('|')[0]
```

or

```
print lyr.dataProvider().dataSourceUri().split('|')[0]
```

Comment: I tried but its prints dbname='/home/farook/Spatialite/Cities.sqlite' table="cities" (geometry) sql= instead of dbname='/home/farook/Spatialite/Cities.sqlite'

Comment: For your case you may have to split at the empty space character between Cities.sqlite' and table instead of the pipe character e.g. .split(' ')[0]