# Get SpatiaLite Database path from Vector Layer in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, spatialite

What if I would like to have the full SpatiaLite database path from a vector layer loaded in the TOC with PyQGIS?

With a very simple example, by storing active vector layer in a variable:

```
vl = iface.activeLayer()
```

one can retrieve the `providerType` and the `dataSourceUri`:

```
vl.providerType()
u'spatialite'

vl.dataProvider().dataSourceUri()
vl.dataProvider().dataSourceUri()
u'dbname=\'/home/matteo/myDataBase.sqlite\' table="river_layer" (geometry) sql='
```

Is there a simple method to get as a string, just the path of the database (so. /home/matteo/myDataBase.sqlite)?

Comment: Thanks Joseph! Do you think (or know) if the method you suggest is also cross-platform? Great pythonic way to solve the problem ;)

Comment: Most welcome! Hmm I can't tell you for sure, I tested this on a Windows machine so if it works for you too then that's two platforms down ;)

Comment: ehehe.. 2 down is good.. Thanks Joseph, if want you can copy and paste your comment as a question so I will accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/189020/getting-the-db-name-of-the-spatialite-table-loaded-inside-qgis-using-pyqgis) but if you only want to extract the **path** of the `dataSourceUri()` (and not `u'dbname=\'/home/matteo/myDataBase.sqlite\'`), you could use:

```
vl.dataProvider().dataSourceUri().split(' ')[0].replace('dbname=','').replace("'","")
```

Which should give:

```
u'/home/matteo/myDataBase.sqlite'
```

Comment: Question about that: Why don't you use `vl.source()` instead of `vl.dataProvider().dataSourceUri()`?

Comment: @YoLecomte - You're correct in that you could use `vl.source()` to extract the uri path which could shorten it to `vl.source().split(' ')[0].replace('dbname=','').replace("'","")`. But typically when using Spatialite (or PostGIS) databases, you use `vl.dataProvider().dataSourceUri()` to not only extract the uri information but also set up the connection parameters. I guess in the end, it's just personal preference :)

Comment: @YoLecomte - Most welcome =)